# Trying to access array offset on category list

Tags: categories

Morning everybody. When I try to click on category list I get this error but it is only with php 7.4. I wonder what could cause this issue.

```
function getparent($parentid, $title) {
global $prefix, $db;
$result = $db->sql_query('SELECT `title`, `parentid` FROM `' . $prefix . '_nsngd_categories` WHERE `cid` = ' . (int)$parentid);
$cidinfo = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);
if ($cidinfo['title'] != '') $title = htmlspecialchars($cidinfo['title'], ENT_QUOTES, _CHARSET) . ' -&gt; ' . $title;
if ($cidinfo['parentid'] != 0) {
    $title = getparent($cidinfo['parentid'], $title);
}
return $title;
```

}

These 2 lines is affecting this function to work properly. I searched over here but I couldn't find the answer.

```
    if ($cidinfo['title'] != '') $title = htmlspecialchars($cidinfo['title'], ENT_QUOTES, _CHARSET) . ' -&gt; ' . $title;
if ($cidinfo['parentid'] != 0) {
```